# How to disable downgrade extension check in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

When I drag an older version extension into `chrome://extensions` page in Chrome, it complains *"Attempted to downgrade extension."* The installation will fail.

[image]

Sometimes I need to install older version extensions. I tried:

- Uninstall current extension first, restart Chrome, then try to install older version extension, still get same error

I know a workaround, is to unpack the extension, and load unpacked extension in Developer Mode.

But I want to know, is there any way to disable this version check in Chrome?

> I don't want to use the workaround, because it doesn't work as expected sometimes. For example, I'm using Native Messaging in my extension, if I load my extension as unpacked, sometimes the native messaging application can't start for unknown reason.